# Finding the difference between two different arrays using JS and FP

Tags: javascript, array, functional-programming

I'm trying to practice functional programing using JavaScript. These pure functions just work together to find the difference between two arrays. I know that this might be an impractical example of functional programing, but could you let me know where I can improve or maybe where I've misunderstood an FP technique?

```
"use strict";

let find = (arr1) => (arr2) => {
  let diff1 = findDiff(arr1)(arr2);
  let diff2 = findDiff(arr2)(arr1);

  return concat(diff1)(diff2);
};

let concat = (arr1) => (arr2) => arr1.concat(arr2);
let findDiff = (arr1) => (arr2) => arr1.filter( (elem) => arr2.indexOf(elem) < 0 );

let sweet = find( [1,2,3,4,5] )( [1,2,3,5,6] );
console.log(sweet);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am concerned that you really haven't defined "difference" here and that perhaps your code does not perform the way you expect.

You example is quite simple in that you would expect `[4, 6]`.  But what if you had arrays like:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

What do you expect to be returned?  Currently, your function would return `[4, 4, 6]`, but is that what you expect, or would each instance of a repeated value need to be treated differently (i.e. return would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]`)?

Have you considered flipping your array values into object keys (if type conversion is not a concern) or using `Array.sort()` on input arrays in combination with `fromIndex` parameter to `Array.indexOf()` to minimize array iteration caused by `Array.indexOf()`? This may not be a concern if you don't expect to be diffing large arrays.

Do you really want to support the `find()()` syntax for this? I don't really see much value in nesting your function calls in this manner vs. just using:

```
let find = (arr1, arr2) => {
    // function logic
}
```

You are not ever returning the intermediate function for possible use elsewhere, so I don't follow the need for this approach.

I agree with the comment from @GregBurghardt around not unneccesarily wrapping native array functions.

I don't like the function being called `find`.  Perhaps something more descriptive to what is actually happening here like `arrayDiff()`. You are not `find`ing here at all.

To me this whole thing would be clearer/simpler like this:

```
let arrayDiff = (arr1, arr2) => {
    return arr1.filter( elem => arr2.indexOf(elem) < 0 )
       .concat(
            arr2.filter( elem => arr1.indexOf(elem) < 0 )
       );
};
```

Note, this obviously does not address some of the questions I asked about uniqueness of array values or optimization of the filter operations.

Comment: Thanks for the insights.  Again I'm just diving into fp. I agree with you and @GregBurghardt about wrapping concat(I don't know why I did that). Thanks gents!

Answer (score 1):

Things look fine actually, except the `concat` function. The problem here is the word "concat" because two things can be commonly concatenated in JavaScript: Strings and Arrays.

The only suggestion I would make is not create a functional wrapper around native functionality.

```
let find = (arr1) => (arr2) => {
  // ...

  return diff1.concat(diff2);
}
```

That's a lot easier to read and understand.